# Reubicar DIV diferentes pantallas

Tags: html, css

Estoy teniendo problemas para ubicar estos DIV dependiendo de si la pantalla es PC o tablet.
El caso es que me gustaría que el cuadrado 1 de la imagen se pusiera justo encima de los cuadrados 2 y 3 de la imagen ocupando todo el ancho cuando la pantalla es más pequeña, por ejemplo para tablet.

Lo he intentado de varias maneras, utilizando grid y flexbox pero no acaba de funcionarme correctamente. ¿Podrían ayudarme a solucionar esto?

[image: Representación DIVS desktop y tablet]

Comment: has probado con meqia query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pues pudes usar Flexbox o Grid, solo que habrá que usar ***media query*** para poder realizar el diseño que necesitas. He realizado un ejemplo para que lo puedas ver mejor.

**Código en HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="square s-1">1</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="square s-2">2</div>
    <div class="square s-3">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Con esto creamos un contenedor principal con un cuadrado principal (en este caso es el 1), y otro contenedor llamado *row* donde tenemos otros dos cuadrados más. Ahora con CSS editamos el código HTML.

**Código en CSS**

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.container .row {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.container .square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .container .square.s-1 {
    width: 210px;
    
  }
}
```

Ahora con esto puesto, lo que conseguimos es usar flexbox para que por defecto el contenedor principal se vea en línea usando *flex-direction: row;* y cuando la pantalla/ventana sea inferior a 768px se cambie el contenedor de manera en columna usando *flex-direction: column;* y que el cuadrado número 1 en vez de tener el mismo tamaño que el resto que tenga el doble para que ocupe la fila de arriba por completo, así para que en dispositivos tablets se vea adaptado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto se puede realizar de varias maneras, incluso con grid es más sencillo pero para que lo puedas entender mejor te lo dejo así. Si necesitas saber algo más coméntalo.